# Create Woocommerce Multi store - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multistore, online-store

I have 3 multiple WordPress with Woocommerce stores that are hosted in individual domains (Sub-domain). I want to create one WordPress Woocommerce it has multiple stores. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok. Let me explain to you the scenario. I have three eCommerce websites that are uploaded on the following domains. The first website is domain1.mycompany.com. The second website is domain2.mycompany.com. The Third website is domain3.mycompany.com.

Comment: All three websites have individual WP, Backend, and individual woocommerce stores which I have difficulties managing the websites. All the above three websites have specific city locations in their respective store.

Now I want one website where it has only one WP, one Backend,  and individual stores for specific cities. I can manage the store by selecting the dropdown from the backend. Like the multilingual websites are worked.

Comment: @WPexpert available to help me on this?

Comment: @IbrahimShabbir Hey .. did you get some solution. I also have similar requirements.

Comment: @RaviSingh no bro.

Answer (score 0):

Check the multivendor plugins (marketplace)
You can also insert on your new site URL redirections to each store

Comment: No, I don't want a multivendor. I want a multi-store on the backend where I can show the user to specific products.

Answer (score 0):

Use woomultistore plugin for Product synchronization.

Comment: Please post this as a comment.

Comment: Use WooCommerce API Product Sync with Multiple plugin.

Comment: Not here, to original question.